# How to use the request in a ModelForm in Django

Tags: django, forms

I would like to make a queryset where the current user is used as a filter in a ModelForm:

```
class BookSubmitForm(ModelForm):
    book = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Book.objects.filter(owner=request.user),)
...
```

Does Django pass the request to the form? Is it good practice? How can I use the request? (of course the name request is not defined)

Edit:

I tried another solution which is to call the form in the view passing it the request:

```
form = BookSubmitForm(request)
```

and then in the form I use this:

```
class BookSubmitForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BookSubmitForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["library"].queryset = Library.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
```

It works and the code is in the form. Now I'm not sure it's the best solution, could it be improved?

Comment: Django docs: [Models and request.user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

No, the request is not passed to the ModelForm. You'll need to do something like this in your view:

```
form = BookSubmitForm()
form.fields['book'].queryset = Book.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
# pass form to template, etc
```

As you said, it's often cleaner to encapsulate this in the Form object, particularly if you have several fields that will need filtered querysets. To do this, override the forms's `__init__()` and have it accept a kwarg of `request`:

```
class BookSubmitForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
        super(BookSubmitForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["book"].queryset = Book.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
        self.fields["whatever"].queryset = WhateverModel.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Then just pass request whenever you instantiate `BookSubmitForm` in your view:

```
def book_submit(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BookSubmitForm(request.POST, request=request)
        # do whatever
    else:
        form = BookSubmitForm(request=request)
    # render form, etc
```

Comment: You're right, it works. I would like to know if it is possible to put the code in the form though, just for organizational purpose and global cleanliness.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, and it's often a good idea in order to keep your view code clean. I've updated with an example.

Answer (score 14):

Extending [AdamKG answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8841565/207241) to class based views - override the `get_form_kwargs` method:

```
class PassRequestToFormViewMixin:
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return kwargs

from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
class BookSubmitCreateView(PassRequestToFormViewMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = BookSubmitForm
# same for EditView
```

and then in forms:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
class BookSubmitForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ...
```