# Django filter the queryset of ModelChoiceField

Tags: django

I'm been using a form field called ModelChoiceField and querying by all the objects but it's not extactly what I intended to use it for.

```
 class PictureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Whiteboard = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Whiteboard.objects.all())
```

I'm been trying to use the ModelChoiceField to query for all the WhiteBoard objects that belong to a particular user

```
Whiteboard = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Whiteboard.objects.filter(user=request.user))
```

but I discovered that the request does not pass to the ModelForm .I'm been searching through SO for various solution and one solution was to override the  forms's **init**()

This is probably the closest question that relate to my problem 
[How to use the request in a ModelForm in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841502/how-to-use-the-request-in-a-modelform-in-django)

**This was his solution .If his solution was to override the queryset at the views . How Does he create the  ModelChoiceField without a queryset at the forms.py**

**In my case , I want filter all the whiteboards by users. How could I do it?**

Parts of my module

```
class Whiteboard(models.Model):

    Category =models.CharField(max_length=30,choices=CATEGORY)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    picture = models.OneToOneField('Picture',related_name='picture',blank=True,null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Picture(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    Whiteboard = models.ForeignKey(Whiteboard,blank=False,null=False,related_name='board')
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/",blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    is_primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description
```

My views.py

```
def PictureCreator(request):
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:LoginRequest'))

if request.method == "POST":
    form = PictureForm(request.POST , request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        picture = Picture(user=request.user)
        image = request.FILES.get('image')
        if image:
                            picture.image = form.cleaned_data['image']
                    description = form.cleaned_data['description']
        if description:
                            picture.description = form.cleaned_data['description']

        if board:
                            picture.board = form.cleaned_data['board']
        picture.save()
        board = Whiteboard.objects.get(Whiteboard=picture.board)
        the_id = board.id
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:Boat', kwargs={'animal_id': the_id }))   

return render(request,'picture.html',{'form':PictureForm()})
```

picture.html

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type = "submit" value= "Add Picture" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Why do you have a `Whiteboard` in your `Picture` model, when you already have a `Picture` in your `Whiteboard` model? You only need one of them. Do whiteboards have pictures, or do pictures have whiteboards?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass `user` in `init` then in your form in the view you must pass the user value `PictureForm(request.user)`

```
class PictureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Picture

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PictureForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Whiteboard'].queryset = Whiteboard.objects.filter(user=user)


def PictureCreator(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:LoginRequest'))

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PictureForm(request.user, request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            picture = Picture(user=request.user)

            image = request.FILES.get('image')
            if image:
                picture.image = form.cleaned_data['image']

            description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            if description:
                picture.description = form.cleaned_data['description']

            if board:
                picture.board = form.cleaned_data['board']
            picture.save()

            board = Whiteboard.objects.get(Whiteboard=picture.board)
            the_id = board.id
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:Boat', kwargs={'animal_id': the_id }))   
    return render(request,'picture.html',{'form':PictureForm(request.user)})
```

Comment: Can I ask , what about the ModelChoiceField! :]

Comment: you can also use that but you can't pass a value, that's the difference

Comment: if your query is like this `Whiteboard.objects.all()` then you can use that as long as you don't need to pass a value

Comment: cathy . I got this error __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: I thought you got an errror?

Comment: It was my mistake .I forgot to put PictureForm(request.user)

Comment: I'm sorry if sometimes . I say stuff that doesn't make sense. It's because of me  ,sometimes I don't even know what i'm doing .

Comment: it's me I just can't understand the question. I'm not good in english :). Sometimes, there are questions here that I can't answer because I don't understand what his saying LOL

Comment: Still posting on your blog? :D

Answer (score 17):

Do not set a filter at all during class definition. You'll override it in your view.

```
form = PictureForm()
form.fields['whiteboard'].queryset = Whiteboard.objects.filter(user=request.user)

class PictureForm(ModelForm):
   whiteboard = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Whiteboard.objects.none(),)
```

Comment: The booksubmitform was an example posted by someone else

Comment: In my situation , I want to filter all the whiteboards by the user. How can I do it?

Comment: I've noticed that you use first letter uppercase in your model attributes definition. Don't do that or you'll potentially override classes

Comment: I tried your answer . it doesn't to work coz it still gives me all the boards

Comment: argument of type 'SimpleLazyObject' is not iterable

Comment: where (in your code) do you receive this error? have you changed your attribure to lowercase as shown in the example?

Comment: Im sorry but it does display all the boards for a particular user but it's conflicting with my save if form.is_valid():