# Django Forms how to access current request user in ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am working on a hard django project and I am stuck again. In my implementation of ModelForm, I have this form. So I wanna filter the queryset in the `assign` field so if I do this `assign.objects.filter(user_id=1)` it is gonna show every user this queryset but I wanna put the request user in this queryset. How can I access the current request user?

```
class SomeModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    assign = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        queryset=Assign.objects.all(),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Hey man, does this answer your question? [How to use the request in a ModelForm in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841502/how-to-use-the-request-in-a-modelform-in-django)

Answer (score 2):

Pass one additional `user` object to your form, and then filter based on the user.

#### forms.py

```
class SomeModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    assign = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        queryset=Assign.objects.none(),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = '__all__'

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       if user:
           self.fields['assign'].queryset = Assign.objects.filter(user=user)
```

#### views.py

```
form = SomeModelForm(user=request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by just writing

```
username = request.user.username
print(username)
```

It will print the current logged in username.