# Django How to get user email in model form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-authentication

So I have the profile update form in Django and I inherit it from `ModelForm`. But I'm unable to get user email by `self.request.user.email`.

```py
class  UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #Profile email 
    email=forms.EmailField()
    username=forms.CharField(required=True,validators=[username_check,])                                                            
    class Meta:
        model =User
        fields =['username','email']
                   
    def clean_email(self):
        form_useremail=self.cleaned_data.get("email").lower()
        if form_useremail!=self.request.user.email and User.objects.filter(username=form_username).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email already in use")
        else:
            return form_useremail
```

I'm getting this error:

```
'UserUpdateForm' object has no attribute 'request'
```

Comment: Why do you expect to see `user` attribute on form instance? What kind of data do you expect to get from `self.user` ?

Comment: you are not trying to get self.request.user.email but self.user.email also this is unnecessary step as exist filtering covers that particular logged in user

Comment: Also you could set unique on field instead https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#unique

Comment: You have to pass the request through context.Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841502/how-to-use-the-request-in-a-modelform-in-django

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev username of current login user.

Comment: thanks for reference question.

Answer (score 1):

You can access to user's email from **self.instance.email**

try it for example:

```
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    user_email = self.instance.email
    if User.objects.filter(email = email).exists() and user_email.lower() != email.lower():
        raise forms.ValidationError('Email already in use')
    return email
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.