# Get current user info inside model form in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have the below code structure. I want to get the `request.user` information inside `StaffForm`.
How do I pass the user info to that class

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
  class StaffForm(UserProfileForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
    class Meta:
      model = models.UserProfile
      fields = ()

  class SuperUserForm(UserProfileForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    class Meta:
      model = models.UserProfile
      fields = ()

  search_fields = [
    'email',
    'name'
  ]
  def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
      return self.SuperUserForm
    else request.user.is_staff:
      return self.StaffForm
```

Comment: Is it not available as `self.request.user`?

Comment: It is not available inside `ModelForm`

Comment: Take a look at this - maybe it's useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841502/how-to-use-the-request-in-a-modelform-in-django#8841565